# Android, array throught two different classes

Tags: android, arrays

I have Activity1, Activity2 and Activity3.
I start Activity3 from Activity1 with startActivity(), but in Activity3 I need an array who can be found in Activity2. How can I get this array from Activity2 class to Activity3 class?

Comment: "found in activity 2"..? What is the role and lifecycle of activity 2? Who launches it? When is it launched? You can pass arguments between activities in intents, but maybe you need to consider storing your data in some shared place instead of keeping it within activity 2?

Comment: be more specific, what is Activity2 role in all of this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to store Activity2's array to a presistent storage, e.g. temp file and read it from Activity3.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and store this Array in some singleton class, some DataManager, which has per-application lifecycle, and take array from any activity in any time.